# Is it possible to set angular-summernote height to parent height?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material, summernote

Title says it all. Im using angular-material with angular-summernote. i would like to be able to set the hight of the summernote box to the full height of the parent `<md-content flex>`. Is this possible? If yes, how?.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem has solved itself! The problem was in angular-material itself.